# center googleVis plot in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, googlevis

I am playing around with googleVis in knitr and typically one can center a plot by using `fig.align="center"`, however, this does not appear to work for googleVis plots.  How can I center a googleVis plot in the middle of the page?

**Here is the MWE Rmd file**

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
```
------
## Page 1

```{r echo = FALSE, results="asis", fig.align="center", messages=FALSE}
dat <- data.frame(party=c("CDU", "FDP", "CSU", "SPD",
                          "The Left", "The Greens"),
                  members.of.parliament=c(193, 93, 44, 
                                          146, 76, 68))
library(googleVis)
## Doughnut chart - a pie with a hole
doughnut <- gvisPieChart(dat, 
                      options=list(
                        width=500,
                        height=500,
                        slices="{0: {offset: 0.2},
                          1: {offset: 0.2},
                          2: {offset: 0.2}}",
                        legend='none',
                        colors="['black','orange', 'blue', 
                        'red', 'purple', 'green']",
                        pieSliceText='label',
                        pieHole=0.5),
                      chartid="doughnut")
print(doughnut, "chart")
```

------
## Page 2


```{r echo = FALSE, fig.align="center"}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gvisPieChart()` function does not create an image, so `fig.align` will not work. You need to add code to center the javascript.

The easiest way to do this is:

```
cat("<center>")
print(doughnut, "chart")
cat("</center>")
```

Using `<center>` is not very good coding (in the HTML world), but it is quick and should work for what you are trying to do.

**EDIT (tyler rinker)**

For me this worked.

I added:

```
img.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

To my style.css and then wrapped the code chunk with `<img class="center"></img>`

Comment: thanks for the response.  You are correct that this indeed does work.  Could you elaborate on the better css/html5 approach you allude to.

Comment: `<center>` is not supported in HTML5 and is deprecated in HTML4. See http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html for centering using CSS, which explains it better than I probably could.